# TYPO3 extbase multiple instance of the same plugin on the same page

Tags: typo3, extbase

TYPO3 6.1

How do I use the multiple instance of the same plugin on the same page ?
I have the extbase extension with front end plugin with flexform switchableControllerActions.
One is "Category list" and another is "items list".

If I click on one category list items, its related items list should show in same page and category list items shold stay there too.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate FE plugins, one contains only `categories` and second only `items` actions  .

Comment: Currently I have done the same. But is there no way to work only with one plugin ?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway what's the problem ? fortunately creating plugin with Extbase (especially in comparison to old-school PI approach)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
tx_yourextension.mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
```